# SIgn pdf with external signature from client Itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am signing a file.

First I prepare the file for signature - I insert an empty container, calculate the hash, I send this hash to the client, they sign it there and I get the signature in the form of a string which then needs to be inserted into the document.
But when saving, an error to the signature is displayed that there was an error in formatting or in saving information for this signature

Hash:

```
public class TestSignPDF {

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSignPDF.class);

private static final String base64 =
        "MIIGKgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIGGzCCBhcCAQExDjAMBggqhQMHAQECAgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCC" +
                "A5swggOXMIIDRqADAgECAhMSAEHNA08eSyCIioAbAAEAQc0DMAgGBiqFAwICAzB/MSMwIQYJKoZI" +
                "hvcNAQkBFhRzdXBwb3J0QGNyeXB0b3Byby5ydTELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUxDzANBgNVBAcTBk1vc2Nv" +
                "dzEXMBUGA1UEChMOQ1JZUFRPLVBSTyBMTEMxITAfBgNVBAMTGENSWVBUTy1QUk8gVGVzdCBDZW50" +
                "ZXIgMjAeFw0yMDAzMDUxMTU4MjFaFw0yMDA2MDUxMjA4MjFaMIGbMScwJQYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhh6" +
                "YmV5YWRpdzUyNkB4bWFpbHNtZS5jb20xLzAtBgNVBAMMJtCY0LLQsNC90L7QsiDQmNCy0LDQvSDQ" +
                "mNCy0LDQvdC+0LLQuNGHMRswGQYDVQQKDBLQndC+0LLRgNC10LPQuNC+0L0xFTATBgNVBAcMDNCc" +
                "0L7RgdC60LLQsDELMAkGA1UEBhMCUlUwZjAfBggqhQMHAQEBATATBgcqhQMCAiQABggqhQMHAQEC" +
                "AgNDAARABcSDHxOPpd2ZTbv/jZNQoFkulrG+3MFRYpFTEA29W/wrIkpidYP3j35MzTvIf6J4Z22n" +
                "+8Dyu/SA5KPaUXg/R6OCAXcwggFzMA8GA1UdDwEB/wQFAwMH8AAwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUH" +
                "AwIwHQYDVR0OBBYEFG5egByngO90EfBatmoTAdNRjoe2MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFE6DPhRp7+xdepUr" +
                "XxH+NzIWSVUrMFwGA1UdHwRVMFMwUaBPoE2GS2h0dHA6Ly90ZXN0Y2EuY3J5cHRvcHJvLnJ1L0Nl" +
                "cnRFbnJvbGwvQ1JZUFRPLVBSTyUyMFRlc3QlMjBDZW50ZXIlMjAyKDEpLmNybDCBrAYIKwYBBQUH" +
                "AQEEgZ8wgZwwZAYIKwYBBQUHMAKGWGh0dHA6Ly90ZXN0Y2EuY3J5cHRvcHJvLnJ1L0NlcnRFbnJv" +
                "bGwvdGVzdC1jYS0yMDE0X0NSWVBUTy1QUk8lMjBUZXN0JTIwQ2VudGVyJTIwMigxKS5jcnQwNAYI" +
                "KwYBBQUHMAGGKGh0dHA6Ly90ZXN0Y2EuY3J5cHRvcHJvLnJ1L29jc3Avb2NzcC5zcmYwCAYGKoUD" +
                "AgIDA0EAktvoNfNTRZ3rGqHm6R/uH5DloTgEzXiRCunoYYXNh1ku8EIEFf298vHdisvA2sa2/fWu" +
                "7PLytY/2i3EtGCKKVTGCAlQwggJQAgEBMIGWMH8xIzAhBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWFHN1cHBvcnRAY3J5" +
                "cHRvcHJvLnJ1MQswCQYDVQQGEwJSVTEPMA0GA1UEBxMGTW9zY293MRcwFQYDVQQKEw5DUllQVE8t" +
                "UFJPIExMQzEhMB8GA1UEAxMYQ1JZUFRPLVBSTyBUZXN0IENlbnRlciAyAhMSAEHNA08eSyCIioAb" +
                "AAEAQc0DMAwGCCqFAwcBAQICBQCgggFSMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZI" +
                "hvcNAQkFMQ8XDTIwMDMxODEzNTM0N1owLwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMSIEIEEWgMAXJ0dl4f4gm0PaQMtY" +
                "zzs6TvsJE0XB6Rb86aJYMIHmBgsqhkiG9w0BCRACLzGB1jCB0zCB0DCBzTAKBggqhQMHAQECAgQg" +
                "9896tvU4aXYE4ecAKTO/PXo3dP/CqFAZmc+RVCp7Ta0wgZwwgYSkgYEwfzEjMCEGCSqGSIb3DQEJ" +
                "ARYUc3VwcG9ydEBjcnlwdG9wcm8ucnUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlJVMQ8wDQYDVQQHEwZNb3Njb3cxFzAV" +
                "BgNVBAoTDkNSWVBUTy1QUk8gTExDMSEwHwYDVQQDExhDUllQVE8tUFJPIFRlc3QgQ2VudGVyIDIC" +
                "ExIAQc0DTx5LIIiKgBsAAQBBzQMwDAYIKoUDBwEBAQEFAARAOFLJIbyLuNqPFuuAa43RnBhOgwjS" +
                "SBy0Sx/TxgwEO263ukc2kDY1TN9se1u1+389yuwBriTw88Wr6V2g+kTCcw==";

@Test
void geHashAndSaveFile() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("com.ibm.security.enableCRLDP", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableCRLDP", "true"); // для проверки по CRL DP
    System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers", "true"); // для загрузки сертификатов по AIA из сети
    System.setProperty("ru.CryptoPro.reprov.enableAIAcaIssuers", "true"); // для загрузки сертификатов по AIA из сети

    BouncyCastleProvider bcProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    String name = bcProvider.getName();
    Security.removeProvider(name); // remove old instance
    Security.addProvider(bcProvider);

    String pathToFile = "hash/no-signed-file.pdf";
    byte[] content = resourceLoader.load(pathToFile);
    String hash = getHash(content);
    log.info("Hash : {}", hash);

}

@Test
void signFile() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("com.ibm.security.enableCRLDP", "true");
    System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableCRLDP", "true"); // для проверки по CRL DP
    System.setProperty("com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers", "true"); // для загрузки сертификатов по AIA из сети
    System.setProperty("ru.CryptoPro.reprov.enableAIAcaIssuers", "true"); // для загрузки сертификатов по AIA из сети

    BouncyCastleProvider bcProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    String name = bcProvider.getName();
    Security.removeProvider(name); // remove old instance
    Security.addProvider(bcProvider);

    String pathToFile = "real_file/SignedPdf2.pdf";
    byte[] content = resourceLoader.load(pathToFile);
    byte[] signed = sign(content, base64, false);

    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(".../real_file/SignedPdf3.pdf")) {
        fos.write(signed);
        //fos.close(); There is no more need for this line since you had created the instance of "fos" inside the try. And this will automatically close the OutputStream
    }


}

public String getHash(byte[] content) throws Exception {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();) {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(content);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, baos, '\0');

        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        sap.setReason("Document Sign");
        sap.setLocation("CryptoPro");
        sap.setReuseAppearance(false);

        ExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
        MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(sap, external, 8192);

        InputStream data = sap.getRangeStream();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("GOST3411-2012-256");
        byte hash[] = md.digest(IOUtils.toByteArray(data));

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(".../real_file/SignedPdf2.pdf")) {
            fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
        }
        return new String(new Base64().encode(hash));
    }
}


public byte[] sign(byte[] rawPdf,
                   String signature,
                   boolean append) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream fout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        byte[] decodeSignature = Base64.decodeBase64(signature);

        CAdESSignature cades = new CAdESSignature(decodeSignature, null, null);
        var certificate = cades.getCAdESSignerInfo(0).getSignerCertificate();
        var subject = new Subject(certificate.getSubjectX500Principal().getEncoded());

        Certificate[] certs = Arrays.stream(cades.getCAdESSignerInfos())
                .map(AdESSigner::getSignerCertificate)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(Certificate[]::new);

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(rawPdf);

        ExternalSignatureContainer container = new BrowserSignatureContainer(Base64.decodeBase64(signature));
        MakeSignature.signDeferred(reader, "Signature1", fout, container);

        return fout.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new InternalException("IO exception by insert signature to document:", e);
    }
}

class BrowserSignatureContainer implements ExternalSignatureContainer {
    private byte[] sinedData;

    public BrowserSignatureContainer(byte[] signature) {
        this.sinedData = signature;
    }

    public byte[] sign(InputStream is) {
        return sinedData;
    }

    public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary pdfDictionary) {
    }
}
```

}

1 - i execute geHashAndSaveFile(), get file SignedPdf2.pdf and hash as a result

2 - seng hash to client and get signed hash as private static final String base64

3 - execute signFile() and get file SignedPdf3.pdf  as a result with nort valid signature;

What is wrong?

Comment: Please share an example PDF signed by your code for analysis of the precise validity issue..

Comment: link : https://yadi.sk/i/e9gI6JjsKULHbg

Comment: At first glance it structurally looks ok. Unfortunately I'm not experienced with GOST algorithms. I'll try and find some time later this week to look into this more deeply. One more question, though, you say the signature is not valid; which validator did you use to test this?

Comment: I just open file in Adope Reader and saw that the signature is not valid,  with message :  an error occurred while attempting to validate this signature

Comment: Please read [here](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSigDC/standards.html), Adobe Acrobat does not support GOST algorithms.